# Can somebody please tell me how to translate this equation into a Java process?

Tags: java, math, equations

I need to know how to translate this:

[image: average]

into a Java process that looks like:

```
public static float computeAverage(float [] i){
//I have no idea what this is supposed to be.
}
```

or perhaps even

```
public static double computeAverage(double [] i){
//Still have no idea what this is meant to be.
}
```

If it's easier to answer with doubles, that's fine, but I really don't need that level of precision.

*Edit:*Okay, tell me if this looks right:

```
public static float computeAverage(float [] i){
    float tally = 0f;
    for(int x=0;x<i.length;x++){
        tally = tally + pValue(i[x]);
    }
    return tally / i.length;
}

public static float pValue(float i){
    return 2 - 1f/i;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is something not working? You should ask more specific questions about what you don't manage to do. "Do-my-work" questions often result in downvotes on SO.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I have no idea how to translate that equation into java code. It's got me completely stumped.

Comment: Also, what is `p()` in your formula? Probability? Shouldn't your method have these as input too, then?

Comment: I can appreciate how people don't like "do my work" requests and rest assured, I really don't like asking people to do that, but I don't know how to even begin translating this

Comment: If you give us the code you have tried maybe someone can modify it to make it work. Right now I just see blank methods, I will keep refreshing till this glitch fixes itself.

Comment: I don't think so. This equation supposedly calculates it's value based only on a bunch of numbers provided that are larger then or equal to 0. I don't think it requires any additional info.

Comment: Start by figuring out what each part of the equation is doing what. Try and break the equation down into different 'parts', whether they're methods, control constructs or variables. For example. I can see that this bit: `(Ci)1<=i<=n` is going to be a variable looping between 1 and n.

Comment: @Cambot If you don't even know what `p()` is here, then check with your teacher, but it's not a Java problem anymore.

Comment: Okay, p can apparrently be figured out by: p(n)−1= 2−1/n−1 = 1−1/n = 1−p(1/n)

Comment: Am I right in assuming that in the equation, "n" refers to the length of the float array being fed into the command?

Comment: @Cambot **WE** should be asking this, this is a question about your requirements, not how to program. That being said, I'm pretty sure this is a good assumption, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to do your work right away, because it won't help you in the future. But I'll try to give you hints.

### Java elements

The different elements that you might need are the following:

- the number `n`, which is the number of elements in your input array, can be accessed using `myInput.length`
- to iterate with a moving `k` index, you'll need a `for` loop. [Check this out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to know how to use `for` loops.
- you'll have to be careful that in Java, arrays are **indexed starting at 0**, not 1. So to access `Ck`, you'll actually write `myInput[k-1]`.

### Break down your problem

What do you want to achieve? You're not just "translating this formula into Java code", but you're writing a method (a function) which, given an input array of `Ci`, returns an average following the specified formula.

I think your assignment is to write the following function:

[image: averagefunction]

Maybe you should try to:

1. write a little method for `p()`
2. write a `for` loop that performs a sum (the internet is full of these)
3. adapt your `for` loop using `p()`
4. divide the result of the `for` loop by `n`
5. return the divided result

---

**UPDATE**: it's much easier to help you once you've tried something :)

Your code looks fine overall now. According to your formula I think you're adding the wrong value to the sum in your loop).

It should probably be: `tally = tally + pValue(i[x])`

Comment: Okay, thanks. It appears that the equation isn't complete enough for my purposes. I understand how arrays and "for" commands work, but I just didn't know how that equation translates into Java code. My hope was that if somebody provided me the code, I could world backwards through it and use it to try and figure out how the equation works.

Comment: @Cambot Look at my edit, it might help you do some steps. If you have specific questions then, edit your post and we'll be glad to answer.

Comment: Okay, according to the equation p(n)−1= 2−1/n−1 = 1−1/n = 1−p(1/n), it would seen that p = 1, as the last 2 parts are identical, except that the 1/n is multiplied by p in the last one. So Ci is my input array? Thanks, that's another hurdle done with. So then I'm supposed to add up all the floats in the array, do I understand that right? And somehow I'm supposed to use p (i.e. 1) for each float? So am I supposed to add 1 to the tally for each item in the array?

Comment: @Cambot I think you're wrong thinking that `p` is a number. IMHO, it is definitely a function. The formula you provide here is just a proof saying that `p(n) = 1 - p(1/n)`. From the beginning of that same formula, I guess that `p(n) = 2 - 1/n`.

Comment: Thanks, Joffrey. I wouldn't have even known where to start without your help :). Java, I can understand, but equations with all those weird symbols like sideways "M"s and stretched out "S"s... I might as well be looking at Egyptian heiroglypics.

Comment: @Cambot Haha, you're welcome. But for the future, keep in mind that if your problem is not with the programming part itself, maybe you should consider posting your question on another forum ;)

Comment: Well, that's the problem isn't it? So often these equations turn out to mean operations that are so complex that there's no real practical way to do them except create a computer program to do them for you. I had no idea whether that equation would translate simply into java or not.